# Select Options Mac Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know if this question is relevant, but it has become an issue at my workplace, so...

One of our clients (using a Mac) showed us a 'problem' in a dropdown that we made using the default  tag. The dropdown has 12 's. In our Windows PC, the dropdown works perfectly fine. i.e the options come below the select tag but in mac this is creating a problem.

This is the Windows screenshot in our PC -
[image]

And this is the Mac screenshot in the client's PC -

[image]

The mac image overlaps the screen, please help me in solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that is just default browser behaviour for some MAC browsers.

Comment: I don't think its an issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery plugin [Selecter](http://plugins.jquery.com/selecter/) or [some else](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/select/)

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely this is a Mac issue.   I checked a page that uses standard `<select>` tags on my Macbook Pro, and in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, the dropdowns are displayed under the tag (as you are looking for).

It may be something related to the specific OS version (I'm using Mavericks), or the specific browser and version (you hadn't specified what browser the user has).

What would help us out here is if you could create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) showing an example of some code you have that works on Windows but not on your Mac.   We could then look and see if there's something specific to the way you have the tag coded, or the CSS, etc.